# self.apos.modules['my-module'] is undefined

Tags: apostrophe-cms

`const myModule = self.apos.modules['my-module']` if I use this in construct of `apostrophe-pages`, where `my-module` is a subclass of `apostrophe-module` is there a chance that `foo` would be `undefined`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because modules are instantiated in a certain order. The order of the standard modules is in `defaults.js` in the `apostrophe` npm module. After that, modules are instantiated in the order found in `app.js`.

As a best practice, you shouldn’t “do things” in `construct`, only assign methods that you then invoke from `afterConstruct` or later. However, in this case, it has to be later, because those other modules still won’t be instantiated yet.

You can safely rely on all other modules existing in a `modulesReady` method. This method is invoked in all modules after the last module is instantiated:

```
module.exports = {
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.modulesReady = function(callback) {
      self.apos.modules['my-module'] ... do something ...
      return callback(null);
    };
  }
}
```

But, you are extending `apostrophe-pages` at project level. And `apostrophe-pages` already has a `modulesReady` method. You could use the `super` pattern to make sure it still gets invoked. But there is a simpler way.

Beginning in Apostrophe 2.63.0, you can use promise events:

```
module.exports = {

  construct: function(self, options) {

    self.on('apostrophe:modulesReady', 'getTheMonkeys', function() {

      const req = self.apos.tasks.getAnonReq();

      return self.apos.modules['monkeys'].find(req).toArray().then(function(monkeys) {
        console.log(monkeys);
      });

    });

  }

}
```

The `getTheMonkeys` argument conveniently defines a `getTheMonkeys` method for this module, in case you want to override its behavior intentionally in a module that extends it. If that doesn't seem important yet, just bear in mind that you must give the event handler a descriptive name inCamelCase which explains what it specifically does.

Notice that code in `modulesReady` runs only once, when the site starts up. This is what code in `construct` does, so it is the correct answer to the question as asked. But for those who want to do something on every page load, not just at startup, the right code would be:

```
module.exports = {

  construct: function(self, options) {

    self.on('apostrophe-pages:serve', 'getTheMonkeys', function(req) {

      return self.apos.modules['monkeys'].find(req).toArray().then(function() {

        // Got all the monkeys on every page load.
        // Now you can access them as `data.monkeys` in your page templates.

        req.data.monkeys = monkeys;
      });

    });

  }

}
```

Notice that here we have a real `req`, so we can attach the data to `req.data` and make it available to the page template. And, the list of monkeys will be up to date each time.

If you are using node 8 or better, you can use async/await, which is even more concise:

```
module.exports = {
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.on('apostrophe-pages:serve', 'getTheMonkeys', async function(req) {
      req.data.monkeys = await self.apos.modules['monkeys'].find(req).toArray()
    });
  }
}
```